# SFINAE on array initialization in VS10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfinae

On [cppreference/variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant)(4) the converting constructor is described as follows:

> Converting constructor. Constructs a variant holding the alternative type `T_j` that would be selected by overload resolution for the expression `F(std::forward<T>(t))` if there was an overload of imaginary function `F(T_i)` for every `T_i` from `Types...` in scope at the same time, except that:
>
> - An overload `F(T_i)` is only considered if the declaration `T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };` is valid for some invented variable `x`;
> - If `T_i` is (possibly cv-qualified) `bool`, `F(T_i)` is only considered if `std:remove_cvref_t<T>` is also `bool`.

As I am tied to Visual Studio 2010 but still want to have a std-variant I implemented one myself. The problem I have and which I am asking for a solution here is how to implement the first bullet point in VS10? How to discard an overload of the imaginary function `F(T_i)` if the expression

`T_i x[] = { std::forward<T>(t) };`

is ill-formed?

In VS15 I am able to write:

```
template<class T> using array_t = T[];

template<class UserType, class T_i, class = void>
struct Single_FUN_T_i {
    using type = void(*)();
};

template<class UserType, class T_i>
struct Single_FUN_T_i<UserType, T_i,
    decltype( array_t<T_i>{ std::declval<UserType>() }, void() )> {
    //        ^^ Here I check whether T_i[]{ declval<T>() } compiles
    using type = T_i(*)(T_i);
};
```

But in VS10 this does not work as the expression `array_t<T_i>{ std::declval<UserType>() }` seems not to be supported (I know that the aliasing template also wont work but that's not the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think, I am not able to solve this problem with VS10. This is for the reason that [the aggregate initilization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) `T object[]{args...}` is only available since C++11 and not part of VS10 yet. And to do SFINAE on aggregate initilization I can't write `decltype(T x[]= {arg})` but would have to write `decltype(array_t<T>{arg})` as in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might get you further. Instead of using array initialisation, use declval to instantiate an array and try and insert elements in it.

// TestSfinae.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility/declval.hpp>

template<class A, class B, class = void>
struct X {
    std::string msg;
    X():msg("Fail"){};
};

template<class A, class B>
struct X<A, B, decltype(boost::declval<A[]>()[0]=boost::declval<B>(), void()) > 
{
    std::string msg;
    X():msg("Pass"){};
};

int main(){
    X<int,int> x;
    std::cerr << x.msg << std::endl;;

    X<int,std::string> y;
    std::cerr << y.msg << std::endl;;

}
```

the result as expected is

```
Pass
Fail
```